# comparison of two arrays and finding the missing elements and from which array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, compare

I have two arrays. I need to find out common element of arrays and what elements are missing and from which array?

I am using the below code to find the common elements in both the arrays and list of missing elements from both arrays.

Can anyone tell me how can I find the list of elements **missing** from each array?

For example:
In below code I need to print element **"ghi"** missing from `@arr2` and element **"mno"** missing from `@arr1`

```
my @arr1 = ( "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" ); 
my @arr2 = ( "mno", "abc", "jkl", "def" );

my %count = ();
foreach $element ( @arr1, @arr2 ){
    $count{$element}++;
}
my @diff = grep { $count{$_} == 1 } keys %count;
my @common = grep { $count{$_} == 2 } keys %count;
```

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Array-Utils/Utils.pm

Comment: May be this question as duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put the items of `@arr1` and `@arr2` also in hashes, you could do:

```
my @miss1 = grep { $count{$_} == 1 && !exists $arr1{$_} } keys %count;
my @miss2 = grep { $count{$_} == 1 && !exists $arr2{$_} } keys %count;
```